# How to get RSpec to test controllers in subdirectories?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have some controllers that are in subdomains of the controllers folder.

for example, i have a controller in `app/controllers/api/v1/offers_controller.rb` that looks like this:

```
class Api::V1::OffersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
   ...some code here
  end
end
```

I tried putting a controller in `spec/controllers/api/v1/offers_controller.rb` that looks like this:

require 'spec_helper'

```
descripe Api::V1::OffersController do
  describe "GET 'index'" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get 'index'
      response.should be_success
    end
  end
end
```

however, when I run `rspec spec`, this test does not get run at all. I also tried putting it  in the `spec/controllers` directory, named api_v1_offers_controller.rb, and the test is still not run.

How can I write RSpec tests for these types of controllers?

Answer (score 4):

It actually seems it was a mistake it how I named the file. it seems all RSpec tests need to end it `_spec`